# Subtracting Time_In from Time_Out in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle-apex, date-arithmetic

I am working in Oracle APEX, i want to Subtract `Att_In` from `Att_Out` to acquire the value in `MINUTES` format.I tried different Queries but giving me the wrong answer or some times give the value in Decimal. Here is the Query.

```
select (to_char(att_In,'HH24:MM:SS')) as time_In,(to_char(att_out,'HH24:MM:SS')) as time_out from attendance;
```

[image]

```
select to_char(att_In,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MM:SSAM'),to_char(att_out,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MM:SSAM'),(att_out-att_in) from attendance;
```

[image]

I need  the value in `Time Format`

Comment: if you want only minutes use: (att_out-att_in)*1440, because the difference is expressed in days and in a day you have 1440 minutes.

Comment: Florin Ghita.. It works. i don't know how to give you vote in comment :)

Comment: No problem. It is a closed question. Glad it works.